# Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

im using xampp and try to connect my login page to mysql database on phpmyadmin
config file to connect

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=regis_system", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

i use default username and password of xampp which is "root" and password is ""
check if default is right or not from confic.inc which say that my server name is host and user name is root with empty password

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3307;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

[db i have created is regis_system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcveB.png)
some advice said Change the collation of my database to "utf8_general_ci" and i already do it.

[also try other host and user but none of them work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klM8O.png)

Comment: It looks to me like the root user does have a password, so you need to use it. Can you access the DB using the command-line tool without a password?

Comment: @Barmar i try to access db using command line with user as root and password as "" and get this error
'''
mysql.exe -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'caching_sha2_password.dll'
'''

Comment: @Barmar so i guess it will need password so i change the password in config.inc.php , db.php, phpmyadmin > user account to new password "root" and then try access it again but it still give error
'''
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ****
ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'caching_sha2_password.dll'
'''

Comment: Sounds like mysql wasn't installed properly. Ask for help on [dba.se].